# How to read response data in http get in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, http, promise, aurelia

I'm creating an application using Aurelia. It connects with a REST API.
When a user logs in, I need to read the response data and add it to the localstorage. This is my code:

```
login(userdata) {
  if (userdata.username !== "" && userdata.password !== "") {
    this.localStorageService.set("login_data", JSON.stringify(userdata));

    return this.http.fetch("login", {
      method: 'post',
      body: json(userdata),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(userdata.username + ":" + userdata.password)
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      // **************** here i need to print response and check it.
      // **************** response.data.me is user object
      return response.json();
    });
  }
}
```

I have commented the place I need to read the response and do the logic. I tried to do it by converting response into JSON, didn't work. And I tried to use a callback function, like a promise. Not working. Please help me on this.

Comment: `here i need to print response and check it.` - no, because you haven't read the body of the response yet ... which is done in `response.json()` - chain another then after what you've got, and there, the data will be available

Comment: .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
         console.log(data);
      });

Comment: @JaromandaX I used like above comment.. I can print data at the service layer.. Thanks you very much for the idea. But now the issue is, the place where I call the service, it get undefined.

Comment: this.steam.login(user).then((data:any) => {
      console.log("controller : ",data);
    });

Comment: @JaromandaX Check above commet. This is the place i'm calling the login service. But console.log("controller : ",data); this comes as undefined. I need to fix that too. Please help me :-)

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/8a9083up/ - if you use that code, does the data get logged in the "login service"?